# JOIN query in mongo to include all fields of primary collections & selected fields of other collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to include all fields of main collections & 2-3 fields of other collections which I have joined in my aggregate func.
I can use $project as

```
> $project:                     
>     { 
>       "_id":1,
>       "currency":1,
>       "studentId":1,
>       ............
>       ............
>       "partners.address.country": 1,
>         "course.courserName": 1
>     }
```

I have over 25 records in main collections & want too it be more dynamic.
Is there any other way so that I don't have to write each & every field of main collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can do using a combination of $project and $addFields but it would be better to compute the list of fields on the application level from performance perspective.

The only valid usecase I can think about is when you don't know all fields of the main collection beforehand.

So assuming the "partners" and "course" come from the $lookup  the pipeline can be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "tmp": {
        "partners": "$partners",
        "course": "$course"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "partners": false,
      "course": false
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "partners.address.country": "$tmp.partners.address.country",
      "course.courserName": "$tmp.course.courserName"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "tmp": false
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: It is working here https://mongoplayground.net/p/NJOs6OQ5OMD The answer illustrates use of aggregation pipeline to exclude all but required fields in the subdocument preserving all fields in the root. As stated in the answer it is based on fair level of assumptions since the original question lacks details. Please be creative applying it to your usecase. It likely won't work if you blindly copy and paste it.